# Perform multiple analysis on a rolling window. Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform multiple analysis on two separate DataFrame at the same time. I want to first detrend the two pandas DataFrame and then apply a customized function to the same window for the 2 datasets. Any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your attempt in code and examples of the datasets?

Comment: My biggest problem is getting started actually. I can define a custom function that can be applied, but I'm not sure how to apply that to two different DataFrames simultaneously. The data set I'm gonna use is a random 1D generated.

Comment: You may find it easier if you combine the two datasets.  Do they have a common value like a timestamp?
```
df1.set_index('time', in_place=True)
df2.set_index('time', in_place=True)
combined_df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```
Then you can fill gaps with `fillna(method='backfill')` or such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `detrend` from `scipy`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import detrend

data1 = np.random.rand(100)
data2 = np.random.rand(100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Data1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Data2'])

def custom_function(window_data):
    return np.mean(window_data)

window_size = 10
stride = 5

df1_detrended = pd.DataFrame(detrend(df1['Data1']), columns=['Data1'])
df2_detrended = pd.DataFrame(detrend(df2['Data2']), columns=['Data2'])
```

Comment: Appreciate the input. The main issue I'm having is performing a rolling window on 2 different DFs without having to combine both DFs. Combining both would be a bit computationally expensive (I have to performing this task repeatedly for about 10,000 DFs, and having to create a new combined DF each time might not be the best solution) and I'm trying to avoid that issue.